# Limiting search only for freight railway/road in overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

The following Overpass Turbo query seems to work, but I want only railways and roads that can be used for freight transportation:

```xml
<osm-script output="xml">
<id-query {{nominatimArea:Nürnberg}} into="area"/>
<query type="way">
  <has-kv k="railway" regv="rail|freight|main|DB Netz"/>
  <area-query from="area"/>
</query>

<!-- added by auto repair -->
<union>
<item/>
<recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<!-- end of auto repair -->
<print mode="body" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Comment: Should the code be the answer to the question in the title? Or do you get a data extract that you did not want? The query seems to run ok.

Comment: Yes , i only want the freight line/freight road distance but it shows  passenger railways too. @AndreJ

Comment: You have to query for `railway:traffic_mode=freight` or `mixed`. But you have to expect that some railways don't have that tag at all.

Comment: @AndreJ  also, would it be possible to see which highway/road does the freight trucks/vans would opt for or use?

Comment: Main criteria for trucks are max height and max weight limits. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Transport_Karte and the rendering rules behind the Garmin map. But keep in mind that somone must have  added the data to OSM.

Comment: Actually im very new to osm so it is kind of difficult to follow you but i will try to look upon it. thank you! @AndreJ

Comment: Do you prefer to get limited subset of things explicitly marked as only for freight or do you prefer to get things not marked as unavailable for freight?